# How to specify which category of the post to use in case of multiple categories

Tags: filters, categories

In my theme, to display the featured post I have to add an extra category "featured". Now I have articles showing featured in the url instead of the main category.
Any help please?
Thanls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends, how these categories are displayed in your theme.

If it's done nicely and with proper use of WP template tags, then that list comes from [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) function (all other functions are using this one).

And at the end of that function you can find

```
return apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories, $id );
```

So it's great news, because it means, that you can write your own filter and remove given category from the lists:

```
function prefix_remove_featured_category_from_post_categories_list( $categories, $id ) {
    // do whatever you want with $categories list
    // for example remove some category from the list
    $categories_to_remove = array(
        'cat-slug-a',
        'cat-slug-b'
    ); // Array of categories slug to be remove. Put your slugs in here

    foreach ( $categories as $index => $single_cat ) {

        if ( in_array( $single_cat->slug, $categories_to_remove ) ) {
            unset( $categories[ $index ] ); // Remove the category.
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'prefix_remove_featured_category_from_post_categories_list', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: They accepted the answer, so it must've worked, but the question was regarding the URL, not anything in the theme. I suppose the in the permalink is also based on `get_the_category()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie commenting wrong answer/question? There is nothing about any URLs in this question ;)

Comment: "Now I have articles showing featured in the url instead of the main category"

Comment: Exactly - if you use category in urls, then it also is generated based on getting list categories (as all other lists of categories ;))

Comment: So the issue with this solution would be that it's hiding the categories from the front-end also, when the question was only about deciding which category to show in the URL.

Comment: The question was about using one category (featured) only for queries (so featured articles can be selected) and minimize other outcomes. Of course you can know it better than OP ;)

Comment: They only mentioned the URL, so I'm not the one who's making assumptions about what OP wants.

Comment: Just add your answer if you have better solution, downvote my answer, if you think it's a bad one. Why are we wasting time on this discussion?